# NHibernate map class with pk also fk

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables `DATA_PERSONELL` which has a primary key of `PERSONNEL_ID`, and `SYS_USER_INFO` which has a primary key of `PERSONELL_ID` which is also a foreign key to the `DATA_PERSONELL` table.

When attempting to map `SYS_USER_INFO`, the only mapping that I've tried which has worked is to map `SYS_USER_INFO.PERSONELL_ID` as an integer, which ultimately doesn't provide access to the data in `DATA_PERSONELL`.

Does anyone know how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Use a one-to-one mapping.

More details here :

- http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one
- http://sdesmedt.wordpress.com/2006/07/24/nhibernate-part-3-mapping-techniques-for-aggregation-one-to-one-mapping/

Comment: I modified the mapping file as per the article, and still have the same errors,

Comment: Errors are - Could not compile the mapping document:

Comment: Could not determine type for: Tmc.Common.Core.TmcPerson, Tmc.Common, NHibernate.Mapping.Column(PERSONNEL_ID)